# makeAlert Function Returns Always False

Tags: swift, alert, uialertview, swift5

The function below always returns false. I tried to put `return` inside of the completion it did not accept either.

Can you please help me?

```
// MARK: - make Alert for user Input
func makeAlert(message: String, defaultButtonText: String, cancelButtonText: String) - > Bool {

  var answer = Bool()

  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

  let actionYes = UIAlertAction(title: defaultButtonText, style: .default) {
    (action) in

    answer = true

  }

  let actionNo = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonText, style: .default) {
    (action) in
    answer = false

  }
  alert.addAction(actionNo)
  alert.addAction(actionYes)
  self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
    print(answer)
  })


  return answer

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use completion like this.

```
func makeAlert(message: String,defaultButtonText: String, cancelButtonText: String, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let actionYes = UIAlertAction(title: defaultButtonText, style: .default) { (action) in
        completion(true)
    }
    
    let actionNo = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonText, style: .default) { (action) in
        completion(false)
    }
    alert.addAction(actionNo)
    alert.addAction(actionYes)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {

    })
}
```

Usage :

```
makeAlert(message: "Test", defaultButtonText: "Test", cancelButtonText: "Test") { (action) in
    if action {
        // Do code for true part
    } else {
        // Do code for false part
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As per the commnet. How to use in FSCalendar

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {
    makeAlert(message: "Test", defaultButtonText: "Yeah", cancelButtonText: "No") { (action) in
        if action {
            calendar.select(date)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to return boolean upon completion of that function as I use FSCalendar. Please see the screenshot. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/129sYjKDhJPNOYXZOjAAKSWssZWBTlq3W/view?usp=drivesdk

It still does not work the way I need it.

Comment: @EvrimDemir Then please add this point in your question so, users can give appropriate answers. Check my updated answere.

Comment: Raja, great it works as expected. Thank you.